# Unhandled exception at 0x0872340b (CAN.dll) in application.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000

Tags: c++

I am a beginner in C++. I am getting Unhandled exception when i am trying to call a function

Can someone please give me a hint ?

Comment: Nowhere in this post do I see `log_file` being *anything* besides NULL. Thus a dereference: `log_file->vLog_Embaserror(Header, "EMBAS");` is not going to end swimmingly.

Comment: @WhozCraig I have removed NULL and still same problem

Comment: Ugh. **It doesn't point to a valid object**. Just removing ` = NULL;` isn't going to solve that. I cannot imagine a way I can say that any simpler, and if it still isn't clear, you need to review how pointers in C++ work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does not show an assignment to the variable. 'log_file'. But the function config_print_error dereferences this pointer. This matches the exception argumemt 0x00000000. If your code example is incomplete you should lookup the exception address 0x278440b in your map file.

Answer (score 0):

In CAN.cpp, you declared a CBaseLogObject pointer and set it to null, then tried to access it. This is what's called a null pointer exception.